# I need a ratio of numerator below 36 to get to closest the following ratio of 38/45 =0.84444444

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is a trivial question to get a ratio in whole numbers. The numerator has to be below or equal to 36 and the denominator below 48. You have to avoid single digits and the best prefered solution is a ratio like 36/43 or 23/30 etc. I need this ratio to get my gear construction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *are* you asking?  38 = 2*19 and 45 = 5*3*3 so 38/45 are already in lowest terms and what you are asking for simply can not be done.  Why did you think it could?

Comment: @fleablood: "Closest" is not the same as equal.

Comment: This isn't the closest, but $0.8444... \approx 0.84 = \frac{84}{100} = \frac{21}{25}$

Comment: I don't see the word "closest" in the question.  In fact I don't see a question.  I was asking for clarification because I don't know what the OP is asking for.  If he wants the closest fraction that's one thing.  If he wants an exact fraction that's another.  If wants this as a sum of fractions (7/9 + 1/15) that's another. Or as a continued fraction is a fourth.

Comment: Well, the word "closest" was in the title.  As I read it, it's a practical question, and a pretty clear one: find the whole number ratio closest to $38/45$ using numerators between $10$ and $36$.  Presumably there's some constraint relating to the number of teeth on the available gears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{27}{32}=0.84375$$ is the closest you can get subject to your constraints.

You need only try every numerator between $10$ and $36$, and find the best denominator for that numerator.

Answer (score 3):

This method is called continued fractions.
$$\frac{38}{45}=1/(1+1/(5+1/(2+1/3)))\\
\frac{11}{13}=1/(1+1/(5+1/2))=0.84615$$
To get the first line, 
$$38/45=1/(45/38)=1/(1+7/38)=1/(1+1/(38/7))=...$$
then to get the second line, delete the final fraction.
EDIT:  A better answer is when the final $1/3$ is replaced by $1/2$, rather than delete it.  The result is Will Orrick's 27/32

Comment: Nice, continued fractions is one of the best methods to get appropriate results for such approximations.

Comment: I was outdone by Will Orrick.  The trick here is to replace the final 1/3 with 1/2

Comment: Right - which is to say, write $\frac{1}3  = \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}$ then truncate just the $1$. But you have the better approach - Will uses brute force - so you should fix your answer.